# How to restrict onEdit to changes in specific cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that performs calculations that I want to be refreshed whenever there are changes to specific cells which contain dependant drop down values.

So whenever one of those cell's values are changed, I want the function to run. I've not used the onEdit function before and don't really have any idea of where to start.

```
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === 'Supply Projections' || e.range.getA1Notation() === 'J5:K6')
  return //my function
```

This is what I have so far but doesn't seem to work. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the function to run on the sheet 'Supply Projections', when any cell in the range J5:K6 is edited, try

```
function onEdit(e) {
var rows = [5, 6];
var cols = [10, 11];
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === 'Supply Projections' && rows.indexOf(e.range.rowStart) > -1 && cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) > -1 ) {
```

//rest of your code
   }
   }

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly!